# How to check if a user is a member of a group in Windows with Ruby?

Tags: windows, ruby

On Windows, how do I check to see if an authenticated user (ex: DOMAIN\User) is a member a local or domain group with Ruby?

In this case Ruby is running on Windows Enterprise Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out "[ruby-activedirectory](http://code.google.com/p/ruby-activedirectory/)" and "[Ruby And ActiveDirectory](http://www.shaunrowland.com/fsync/?p=67)" seems like that might be of value.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd just `system` out to [ifmember.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=07C2F6D7-815E-4FA0-9043-4E4635CCD417&displaylang=en&displaylang=en)